# unwanted jquery update of PHP variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am submitting a form with Jquery and AJAX, and then only refreshing two single DIVS to display the result. However, it seems to be updating some PHP variables that are not inside of those DIVS. I was under the impression that jquery would leave everything alone, except for the segments you assign to refresh. I am using the code below to return the result of the form sumbit.

```
   $('#divcontainer').load('page.html #div');
```

I need the PHP variables that were present before the form submit to stay the same. I would first like to know if I am wrong, and I should be looking elsewhere for the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Updating some PHP variables"? When the HTML document is output, PHP has already run.

Comment: From the results, I am assuming that the PHP query is being ran every time the form is submit. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be changing anything in the main document except inside `#divcontainer` if you properly catch the submit and redirect it to the Ajax call you show above

Comment: That is the problem. The content reflected directly relies on a SQL ranking that the form is changing in the database. I need to somehow disable the PHP updating when the form is submitted.

Comment: there's no easy way to do that. When you run an Ajax request, that is a separate request and a new instance of the PHP script will be created. If you need to change that, you need to somehow "freeze" the variables (e.g. in a session)

Comment: Thank you for validating my guesses at what was going wrong. It is a start.